# what does B1 and B2 in second order pointwise mutual mutual information mean?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, nlp

I need to know how can i get [image]  and[image]?

[image]

gama here refers to what ?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a similarity measure of PMI? If it's the similarity you're asking, which similarity measure did you get the formula from?

Comment: I'm asking about SCO-PMI, here i want to know what this symbols refer to ? Beta1 , Beta2

Answer (score 2):

I think the metric you're using is from this paper (though the form they give is not quite the same as yours):

> Islam, A. and Inkpen, D. 2006. "Second Order Co-occurrence PMI for
>   Determining the Semantic Similarity of Words".  In *Proceedings of the
>   International Conference on Language Resources and Evaluation (LREC
>   2006)*, Genoa, Italy, pp. 1033–1038.

which is available online [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228615350_Second_order_co-occurrence_PMI_for_determining_the_semantic_similarity_of_words).

They give the following rule for setting beta:

[image]

where delta is a constant whose value depends on the size of the corpus.  Islam & Inkpen use 6.5, but you should probably look at the original paper to get a sense of the trade-offs involved.

Comment: Thanks for helping, i read this paper before can i give delta any number ? and n in the rule refers to what ?

Comment: n is the number of word types in the corpus.  Reading the paper might help, but I get the sense from it that the authors pretty much set delta by trial and error, so you might want to just try some different values and see what kinds of results you get.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping, but i searched for what beta refers to ..!? i didn't found.and i edited new rule in the post and also can't know Gama refers to what? really thanks for helping